# Reading from CSV file and create object

Tags: java, arrays, csv, oop, object

I'm a complete beginner to Java and I have been given an exercise where I have to read data from a CSV file and then create an object for each line of the file as the program reads the data from the file.

Here is part of the CSV file:

```
1,Jay, Walker,91 Boland Drive,BAGOTVILLE,NSW,2477
2,Mel, Lowe,45 Ocean Drive,MILLERS POINT,NSW,2000
3,Hugh, Manatee,32 Edgecliff Road,REDFERN,NSW,2016
4,Elizabeth, Turner,93 Webb Road,MOUNT HUTTON,NSW,2290
```

and so on ...

Here is my code that reads data from the CSV file:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client_19918424 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File inFile = new File("clients.txt");
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(inFile);
        String str;
        String[] tokens;
        while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
            str = inputFile.nextLine();         // read a line of text from the file 
            tokens = str.split(",");            // split the line using commas as delimiter
            
            System.out.println("Client ID: " + tokens[0]);
            System.out.println("Client First Name: " + tokens[1]);
            System.out.println("Client Sur Name: " + tokens[2]);
            System.out.println("Street Address: " + tokens[3]);
            System.out.println("Suburb: " + tokens[4]);
            System.out.println("State: " + tokens[5]);
            System.out.println("Postcode:" + tokens[6]);
            System.out.println( );
                
        } // end while
    }
}
```

this is my Client class (have constructor):

```java
public class Client {
    private int clientID;
    private String firstName;
    private String surName;
    private String street;
    private String suburb;
    private String state;
    private int postcode;
    
    // constructor
    public Client (int ID, String fName, String sName, String str, String sb, String sta, int pCode) {
        
        clientID = ID;
        firstName = fName;
        surName = sName;
        street = str;
        suburb = sb;
        state = sta;
        postcode = pCode;
    }
```

However I don't know how to create a `Client` object for each line of text file as the program reads data from file.
like for the first line make something like this:

```java
Client client1 = new Client(1, "Jay", "Walker", "91 Boland Drive", "BAGOTVILLE", "NSW", 2477);
```

And then add it to array:

```java
Client[0] = client1;
```

can someone help me to solve this question, im really appreciate.

Comment: thanks next time i will remember forgive me becasue this is the first time i post a question

Comment: I suggest that you read this Web page: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Hi hoang, this question may very well be closed as the community requires that members ask questions that show research and some familiarity with the language being used. In your case you may need to brush up on fundamentals of variables in Java. Assuming your main method is printing out everything correctly that means you already have the data you need to create a client (ie. `client=new Client(tokens[0], tokens[1], ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there.
All that's left to do is to map each token that is already printed to the corresponding fields in the `Client` class. Since `token[0]` doesn't really tell what value it holds you could do it in three ways:

```
 while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
    str = inputFile.nextLine();        
    tokens = str.split(",");           
    // Because tokens[0] is of type String but clientID is of type int,
    // we need to parse it and get the integer representation.
    int clientID = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
    // Both of type String, no parsing required.
    String firstName = tokens[1];
    String surName = tokens[2];
    String street = tokens[3];
    String suburb = tokens[4];
    String state = tokens[5];
    int postcode = Integer.parseInt(tokens[6]);
    // Then all that's left to do is to create a new object of `Client` type
    // and pass all the gathered information.
    Client client = new Client(clientID, firstName, surName, street, suburb, state, postcode);
    System.out.println(client + "\n");
}
```

At this moment if we try to print the client (last line) we will get something like this: `com.example.demo.Client@30a3107a`. That's because we didn't tell how we want our object to be displayed. For that `toString()` method in `Client` class has to be overriden like so:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Client ID: " + clientID + "\n" + "Client First Name: " + firstName + "\n" 
           + "Client Sur Name: " + surName + "\n" + "Street Address: " + street + "\n" 
           + "Suburb: " + suburb + "\n" + "State: " + state + "\n" + "Postcode: " + postcode;
}
```

It will give the exact output that is in your example.

It is achievable to create the class by passing those tokens directly as well, without the creation of temporary variables:

```
Client client = new Client(Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]), tokens[1], tokens[2], tokens[3], tokens[4], tokens[5], Integer.parseInt(tokens[6]));
```

This case brings us to the third solution with setters and getters.
The variables that describe the `Client` are already defined, it is possible to pass them to assemble the perfect object, but it is not possible to retrieve them. Instead of setting the variables directly in the constructor, we can create a special method that will do the job, for instance:

```
// Other fields omitted
private int clientID;

// The empty constructor required for later usage,
// since right now, we can't create the object without specifying every property.
public Client() {
}

// This method does exactly the same thing that was done before but
// in the constructor directly
public void setClientID(int clientID) {
    this.clientID = clientID;
}

// This method will assist in retrieving the set data from above.
public int getClientID() {
    return clientID;
}
```

And then the `while loop` would look like this instead:

```
Client client = new Client();
client.setClientID(Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]));
client.setFirstName(tokens[1]);
client.setSurName(tokens[2]);
client.setStreet(tokens[3]);
client.setSuburb(tokens[4]);
client.setState(tokens[5]);
client.setPostcode(Integer.parseInt(tokens[6]));
```

And to get those values:

```
System.out.println("Client ID: " + client.getClientID());
```

Or you could use the constructor with the fields to create the client, add getters in the class, omit both setters, and the empty constructor if the creation of the client should only be possible with all the fields present.

Comment: thanks you very much for helping, however in the first solution at Client client = new Client(clientID, firstName, surName, street, suburb, state, postcode); there are all 7 red lines under each clientID,.... and eclipse show the problem is that (...) cannot be resolved to variable with (...) illustrate each variable when creating client object

Comment: Did you change something in the constructor? The solution will work provided the constructor looks exactly the same as in the question. It might be that some types were modified or some field no longer in there?